# Multiple image upload codeignitor

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, file-upload

I create image upload code. This creates a directory first and then uploads images to it.

In the form, I upload 3 images.

My Code is:

```
$dir_path = 'assets/images/product_images/'.$model;
mkdir($dir_path, 0777);

$i = 1 ;

    foreach ($image as $new_image)
        {
            $dir_path_up = 'assets/images/product_images/'.$model."/";
            $filename = $_FILES["$new_image"]["name"];
            $image_name  = $dir_path_up .$filename . $i. ".jpg";
                echo $image_name;

                $i++;
        }
        die();
```

Result of echo

```
assets/images/product_images/255_2555/1.jpg
assets/images/product_images/255_2555/2.jpg
assets/images/product_images/255_2555/3.jpg
```

But that images are not getting uploaded into the directory. I echo the image name which I created. It's already been renamed. Then why are images not getting uploaded into the directory?

What is wrong with this??

Comment: you forget to write move updoad command in your code?

Comment: @saty Explain please

Comment: what you use core php or codignator?

Comment: http://www.formget.com/codeigniter-upload-image/ Check This

Comment: https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This work fine with **multiple image upload**

```
<?php
    $j = 0;     // Variable for indexing uploaded image.
    $target_path = 'assets/images/product_images/' . $last_id . '/';     // Declaring Path for uploaded images.
    for ( $i = 0; $i < count($_FILES['image']['name']); $i++ )
    {
        // Loop to get individual element from the array
        $validextensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");      // Extensions which are allowed.
        $ext = explode('.', basename($_FILES['image']['name'][$i]));   // Explode file name from dot(.)
        $file_extension = end($ext); // Store extensions in the variable.
        $target_path = $target_path . md5(uniqid()) . "." . $ext[count($ext) - 1];     // Set the target path with a new name of image.
        $j = $j + 1;      // Increment the number of uploaded images according to the files in array.
        if ( ($_FILES["image"]["size"][$i] < 100000000)     // Approx. 100kb files can be uploaded.
            && in_array($file_extension, $validextensions)
        )
        {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'][$i], $target_path);
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

---

Update, you can use

```
foreach ($image as $new_image)
{
    $dir_path_up = 'assets/images/product_images/'.$model."/";
    $filename = $_FILES["$new_image"]["name"];
    $image_name  = $dir_path_up .$filename . $i. ".jpg";
    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["$new_image"]["tmp_name"], $image_name))
    {
        echo "The file has been uploaded.";
    }
    else
    {
        echo "There was an error uploading the file.";
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Read manual from here [CI image upload](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/file_uploading.html).

In codignator we use upload library to upload image .

you pass youe parameter according to your requirment

```
           $config['upload_path'] = 'assets/images/product_images/'.$model."/";
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
            $config['max_size'] = '100';
            $config['max_width']  = '1024';
            $config['max_height']  = '768';

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
            {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());

                $this->load->view('Your View', $error);
            }
            else
            {
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());

                $this->load->view('Your View', $data);
                }
```

Comment: in this case how to rename image??

Comment: after upload or before upload?

Comment: want rename before upload

Answer (score 3):

When you upload a file with PHP it gets stored into a temporary folder.
You can access this file in your script with $_FILES, but it is still in your temporary folder it will be deleted upon next request.

To keep your uploaded File, you need to move it to the desired location.

The function for this is called move_uploaded_file (API: http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php)

```
bool move_uploaded_file ( string $filename , string $destination )
```

In your case it would result in something like:

```
$dir_path = 'assets/images/product_images/'.$model;
mkdir($dir_path, 0777);

$i = 1 ;

    foreach ($image as $new_image)
        {
            $dir_path_up = 'assets/images/product_images/'.$model."/";
            $filename = $_FILES["$new_image"]["name"];
            $tmp_name = $_FILES["$new_image"]["tmp_name"]
            $image_name  = $dir_path_up .$filename . $i. ".jpg";
            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $image_name);
                echo $image_name;

                $i++;
        }
        die();
```

Comment: So there is no index "5.0-Reflective.jpg" in $_FILES, the error states, ,therefore it cannot be uploaded. I do not even know where your $image array comes from, neither where it is filled with what. I am not sure how to help you on this. You need to figure it out by yourself or provide more info on what you are doing.