# I can't upload image using codeigniter

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, file-upload

I want to upload image to database using CodeIgniter I use the following code. Now it shows the error "You did not select a file to upload." even though I had chosen. can any one please say what is the mistake on my code.

```
<?php


class Register_form_controller extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper(array('form','url'));
        $this->load->library('form_validation','validation');
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('name','name','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('age','age','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('gender','gender','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('mobilno','mobilno','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('email','email','required|valid_email|is_unique[register.email]');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('uname','username','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password','password','required|matches[cpassword]');
        $this->form_validation->set_message('cpassword','password mismatched','required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('cpassword','cpassword','required');
        if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE)
        {
            $this->load->view("Register_form_view");

        }
        else
        {
            $this->doregister();
        }
    }
    function doregister()
    {
        if($this->input->post("submit"))
        {           
            $config = array(    "upload_path"   =>  "image/",
                                "allowed_types" =>  "jpg|gif|jpeg|png",
                                "max_size"      =>  "2048",
                                "max_width"     =>  "",
                                "max_height"    =>  ""
                                );

            $this->load->library("upload",$config); 
            if($this->upload->do_upload('image'))
            {
                $upload_data = $this->upload->data(); //echo"<pre>"; print_r($upload_data); exit;

            }
            else
            {

                echo $error =  $this->upload->display_errors(); //echo"<pre>"; print_r($error); exit;
            }

            $name = $this->input->post('name');
            $age = $this->input->post('age');
            $gender = $this->input->post('gender');
            $mobno = $this->input->post('mobilno');
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $uname = $this->input->post('uname');
            $pass = $this->input->post('password');
            $cpass = $this->input->post('cpassword');
            $image = $upload_data['file_name'];
            $data = array(  'name'      =>  $name,
                            'age'       =>  $age,
                            'gender'    =>  $gender,
                            'mobilno'   =>  $mobno,
                            'email'     =>  $email,
                            'uname'     =>  $uname,
                            'password'  =>  $pass,
                            'image'     =>  $image
            );
            //echo"<pre>"; print_r($data); exit;
            //$this->load->library('form_validation');
            $this->load->model("Register_model","register");

            if($this->register->insertData($data))
            {
                $this->load->library("email");
                $this->email->from('magesh0312@gmail.com');
                $this->email->to($email);
                $this->email->subject('Confirmation message');
                $message = "you Registred successfully \n";
                $message = "Thank you for joining";
                $this->email->message($message);
                if($this->email->send())
                {
                    echo 'success';
                    echo"Registred successfully";
                }
                else
                {
                    echo "mail has send failed";
                    echo"  but you joined the group";
                }
                //redirect('Register_form_controller/index');
            }
        }
        else
        {
            echo"registration failed";
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: image path is placed out side application folder??

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image upload not working in codeignitor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29698048/image-upload-not-working-in-codeignitor)

Comment: what problem you facing?

Comment: i can't upload image it display the error message "You did not select a file to upload."even though i select the image

Comment: @wolfgang1983 But that's not a problem here i changed it for several times.

Answer (score 0):

```
     function doregister()
        {
        if($this->input->post("submit"))
        {           
            $config['upload_path'] = './image/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|gif|jpeg|png';
            $config['max_size']    = '2048';
            $config['max_width']  = '1024';
            $config['max_height']  = '768';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

             if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
 {
 $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
 $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);
 }
 else
 {
            $data=$this->upload->data();

            $name = $this->input->post('name');
            $age = $this->input->post('age');
            $gender = $this->input->post('gender');
            $mobno = $this->input->post('mobilno');
            $email = $this->input->post('email');
            $uname = $this->input->post('uname');
            $pass = md5($this->input->post('npassword'));// important config md5 password
            $cpass = md5($this->input->post('cpassword'))// important config md5 password;
            $file= array(  'name'      =>  $name,
                            'age'       =>  $age,
                            'gender'    =>  $gender,
                            'mobilno'   =>  $mobno,
                            'email'     =>  $email,
                            'uname'     =>  $uname,
                            'password'  =>  $pass,
                            'image'     =>  $data['file_name']
                            );

                $this->load->model("Register_model","register");

                if($this->register->insertData($file))
                {
                    $this->load->library("email");
                    $this->email->from('magesh0312@gmail.com');
                    $this->email->to($email);
                    $this->email->subject('Confirmation message');
                    $message = "you Registred successfully \n";
                    $message = "Thank you for joining";
                    $this->email->message($message);
                    if($this->email->send())
                    {
                        echo 'success';
                        echo"Registred successfully";
                          redirect('your_page');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        echo "mail has send failed";
                        echo"  but you joined the group";
                    }
                }
            }

           } else {
              echo"registration failed";
           }
        }
```

Comment: Thank u for your answer but i receive the same error "You did not select a file to upload.."

Comment: i coded just simple registration form using CI. and i want to add image on that like choosing profile image.

Comment: sorry mistake was on my form not in the code i mentioned sorry again

Answer (score 0):

Hey i got the same error multiple time my all php codes is always right but i always forgot `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in form tag check did you add this in your form

```
<form action="demo_post_enctype.asp" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

if don't add `enctype="multipart/form-data"` in your form tag codeigniter always complain `You did not select a file to upload` For more info of uploading image in codeigniter check this [link](http://only4ututorials.blogspot.in/2014/04/pagination-with-codeigniter.html)

Comment: yes i used that but i'm sorry i had open another form using form_open by that only i got that error. thank u i cleared that error.