# Uploading multiple images in codeigniter?

Tags: php, image, codeigniter

I'm currently building a portfolio site for a client, and I'm having trouble with one small area. I want to be able to upload multiple images (varying number) inline for each portfolio item, and I can't see an obvious way to do it.

My view.php:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart('uploadfile/upload');?>

    <fieldset>
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <label for="filename[]" class="control-label">Select File to Upload</label>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="file" name="filename" size="20" />
                    <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($error)) { echo $error; } ?></span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" class="btn btn-primary"/>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <?php echo form_close(); ?>
    <?php if (isset($success_msg)) { echo $success_msg; } ?>
    </div>
```

my controller

```
if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
ini_set("display_errors",1);

class Update_profile extends CI_Controller {

     function __construct()
     {
          // Call the Model constructor
          parent::__construct();
          $this->is_login();
          $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
          $this->load->model('Edit_profile'); 

     }


    public  function index() {

    //  $this->load->view('header2');
        $this->load->view('edit_profile');

    }// index function ends

    public function is_login() {

      $is_login=$this->session->userdata('is_login');
      if(!isset($is_login) || $is_login !=true)
      {
        //don't echo the message from controller 
        echo "you don't have permission to access this page <a href=../Homecontroller/index/>Login</a>";
        die();
      }
  } //is_login function ends

  // function to upload images
    function upload()
    {

        $name_array = array();
        $count = count($_FILES['filename']['size']);
        foreach($_FILES as $key=>$value)
        for($s=0; $s<=$count-1; $s++) {
        $_FILES['filename']['name']=$value['name'][$s];
        $_FILES['filename']['type']    = $value['type'][$s];
        $_FILES['filename']['tmp_name'] = $value['tmp_name'][$s];
        $_FILES['filename']['error']       = $value['error'][$s];
        $_FILES['filename']['size']    = $value['size'][$s];  

        //set preferences
        $config['remove_spaces']=TRUE;
    //  $config['encrypt_name'] = TRUE; // for encrypting the name
        $config['upload_path'] = './upload/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|gif';
        $config['max_size']    = '10248';

        //load upload class library
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        if (!$this->upload->do_upload('filename'))
        {
            // case - failure
            $upload_error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
            $this->load->view('edit_profile', $upload_error);
        }
        else
        {
            // case - success
            $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
            $name_array[] = $data['file_name'];
            $data['success_msg'] = '<div class="alert alert-success text-center">Your file <strong>' . $upload_data['file_name'] . '</strong> was successfully uploaded!</div>';
            $this->load->view('edit_profile', $data);

        }
    }
    }

    function edit_profile() {
    //echo "some success";

    } //function edit profile ends
}
```

code above not working

Comment: why my controller code look so sophisticated

Comment: ooph so much of code didn't formatted the code properly

Comment: possible duplicate of [Image upload not working in codeignitor](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29698048/image-upload-not-working-in-codeignitor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what I've used for the last year when I've wanted/needed multiple image uploads in codeigniter:

https://github.com/stvnthomas/CodeIgniter-Multi-Upload